# Number sequence generated IDs - Efficient way to my possible worst scenario

Tags: php, mysql, function, datetime, stored-procedures

**My setup:**

Mysql  and PHP

**System Scenario:**

I have more than 10 Type of system Users:
For example :Customer and Employee

Everytime a customer or employee added to the system, the system will automatically generate ID to each user based on current date.

**Ex (Customer):**

> Today is June 20,2015 and this customer is the 3rd to sign up. So his
> ID would be **06202015-03**. So everytime a user (any type of user) signup
> the sequence number will increment by 1 in a day basis only. Every next day
> the sequence counter will be back to 0.

**General Question:** Given my concern of ID generation is solved, is it a good practice to **pre-process** the next sequence #? I mean the system will just pullout the next sequence number saved on the db table? or should I just process the next sequence number only until a new user is signing up?

**UPDATE (Added best possible scenario) :**

> Example Date: June 20,2015

1. Customer 1 signup = Generated ID would be 06202015-01
2. Customer 2 signup = Generated ID would be 06202015-02

   and so on...

**Worst possible scenario during signup:**

1. 2 or more user signing up simoltaneously
2. If customer1 is deleted (by admin) on that same day and customer2 signed up, the customer 2 should get the #1 id (06202015-01) and not *-02 as the customer1 is being deleted already.

.

**I would like to know the best way to generate a sequence number efficiently:**

> 1. Is stored procedure would be the best fit for this? or should I use #2?(*see below*)
> 2. Is it a good practice to just process the next sequence number (using PHP function) everytime a user signed up?
>
> *The #2 process is I think the best and easier way to process auto ID generation but I'm thinking WHAT IF 2 or more users
> simultaneously singing up?*

On my latest update, the sequence is obviously predictable. My only concern is what is the best or efficient way to get the sequence number. Is it thru stored procedure or using php script function given the worst scenarios stated.

Comment: What if 100 people sign up on a given day? This is a bad idea. Just store the date, and a unique user id.

Comment: @Strawberry .. No, I mean its not about 100 people signing up. My least concern is: lets say 2 people simultaneously sign-up? The issue is when to get the correct next sequence number in a day. I've updated my post.

Comment: @Strawberry is correct.  Do not do this at all.  just make a unique id number - then store the other attributes in a table - the way a database is intended to work.

Comment: also, there is no such thing as simultaneously.  one will come before another - you can read up on concurrency

Comment: @Randy I guess you are right sir but given the scenarios and also part of the requirement to not to use any auto unique PK other than the said date+sequence # setup, then I coudnt think of any better idea to implement it. It should be that way where the Primary key should be the whole date+sequence # for each day.
.

Using most of your suggestion, the result would be 1 separate unique PK and the other attributes are stored separately then concatenate it for display. Am I right? If this is true, then my date+sequence # is not purely the PK w/c is not the requirement.

Comment: well certainly you can do what you want.  I would caution however that a requirement specification should not generally specify the structure of a concatenated PK - that should be an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

> General Question: Given my concern of ID generation is solved, is it a good practice to pre-process the next sequence #? I mean the system will just pullout the next sequence number saved on the db table? or should I just process the next sequence number only until a new user is signing up?

If the id is dependent on the date an user signs up, you can't predict the next id because you don't know **when** the next user will sign up (unless you are a clairvoyant).

To make it easier to obtain the next value I would split the id into two columns, a column with the date and a column with the sequence, then u can use:

```
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(sequence) FROM usertable WHERE signup_date = CURRENT_DATE), 0) + 1
```

Imo there's no best practise, it's a personal preference.
There's also a third option, a before insert trigger.

To avoid duplicates add an unique index with both columns.

In addition you can lock the table:

```
LOCK TABLES user_table WRITE;
/* CALL(sproc) or INSERT statement, or SELECT and INSERT statements */
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

With a write lock no other session can access the table untill the lock is released (it will wait)

Comment: updated my post to answer your concern. IT IS possible to predict next sequence number in a day.